# Mongodb 2.6 drop collection locking

Tags: mongodb

I am planning to drop a collection which has a storage space of
42gb with indeces, 2x 22gb with indeces and 3.6gb with indeces.

will it take a long time to drop each? 
and will it lock a long time or just a few minutes?

when dropping these. I know it wont reclaim space. right now our disk space is on 90%. so when we drop these, will it still increment disk space? 
or just take up the dropped collections space?

Using monbodb 2.6.12

Comment: What specific version of MongoDB are you using (`db.version()` in the `mongo` shell)? Drop behaviour depends on the storage engine used: WiredTiger (default storage engine in all non-EOL versions of MongoDB) will free the space from the collection & indexes, while the older MMAP storage engine will only mark the space available for reuse.

Comment: using mongodb 2.6

Comment: The specific version of MongoDB (2.6.x) would be helpful in case there are any known issues. Dropping a collection with MMAP in MongoDB 2.6 will require a write lock on the affected database for the duration, however the drop command should be quick. Is this deployment standalone, replica set, or sharded? Dropping a collection or index marks the space as available for re-use for other collections in the same database, but does not have to delete individual documents or index entries. If you are concerned about timing, I recommend testing in a representative staging/dev environment.

Comment: Also worth noting that the [MongoDB 2.6 series reached end of life in October, 2016](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/mongodb-2-6-end-of-life). If disk space is a major concern I suggest you test & plan migrating to a supported MongoDB release series (currently 3.2 or newer) and use the WiredTiger storage engine. The WiredTiger storage engine is now the default for new deployments, and includes index & data compression which can result in significant storage and I/O savings over MMAP. There are also many new features and improvements since the MongoDB 2.6 series which started in March, 2014.